# Shared folders in VMware workstation

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

In VMware workstation is there a way to share an already existing folder in a guest operating system, with the host operating system? I tried following [these instructions](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html) but they seem to be written for someone wanting to share a folder already existing on the host operating system.

Comment: Just share in on the local network and access from within the guest os

Comment: care to elaborate? What is "local network"?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your virtual machine's network connection settings and select "Bridged: connected directly to the physical network".

Then share some folders on your guest OS, via right-clicking menu, from the "sharing" tab.

This should let you access files on guest OS under VMWare Workstation from host OS.

---

Alternatively, you can publish your files for external access (internet-wide, may require external IP address) and simply access them using FTP server or remote connection from any OS with internet access.

Comment: I think you missunderstand the  problem. Say in a guest operating system there is a folder with a lot of source code. How do you get it over to the host operating system? Your way seems to be assuming the other direction.

Comment: So instead of specifying a host path I want to specify a guest path to the shared folder

Comment: @Celeritas Edited to solve your problem.